# When was the first time that a human skull with a black raven sat upon it was used to refer to Edgar Allan Poe?

Tags: history-of, edgar-allan-poe

I am curious about when was the first time (novel, tale, paint, drawing, etc.) that the iconic human skull/raven motif was used to refer to the Master of the Macabre, Edgar Allan Poe?

Comment: Quoth the raven, probably on a book cover; https://www.gohd.com.sg/wp-content/uploads/2015/04/The_Raven___Edga_552fb92c45b04.jpg although he was sat upon an bust of Pallas

Comment: Is this a question about science fiction or fantasy?

Comment: @Laurel - It's about the history of an icon associated with a fantasy author; "*Behind-the-scenes and fandom information*"

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The image of something raven-like (an hour glass with raven's wings, as a symbol of Death) on a skull certainly goes back a long way.  [Gottfried Wilhelm Sacer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gottfried_Wilhelm_Sacer) made a woodcut of the image in the middle to late 1600s:

[image]

As for Poe, certainly the illustrations of Carling and Doré (in specific, those for The Raven) of the mid-late 19th century at least place the raven properly on the bust of Pallas, if not an actual skull.

I think this is one of Carling's creepier ones:

[image]

Doré's version:

[image]

Most of the raven on skull imagery I'm finding appears rather newer, so perhaps not quite the answer you're looking for!